# Menu links not working in Ubuntu (D7)

Tags: 7, routes, database

I had a site in Windows installed inside xampp.  I copied the same `site's folder` and `database` from windows-xampp installation to Ubuntu's www folder (Lamp) . The menu links are not working now. `localhost/sitename` directs to the homepage . But when I click on any menu items , it says

> The requested URL /sitename/latest/11 was not found on this server.

I could not figure out if this is problem of localhost or menu or database?

I can't even login because `users/login` is also not working.

Any suggestion or any links to the articles that I should read to solve this problem  would be great. Thank you .

Comment: Have you tried `user/login` to login? (note `user` not `users`)

Comment: Yes I did but does not work.Gives the same error.

Comment: Sounds like .htaccess did not copy over with the rest of the files. Check to see if that file is present in the site's root folder.

Comment: I checked for .htaccess file . It is present there .

Comment: Are you using the same database name in ubuntu..all credentials stuff?

Comment: Yes I am using the same database name . Choster's answer helped me . Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion is that Drupal's .htaccess URL rewrite directives have been disallowed in your Ubuntu installation of Apache. If it were a bootstrap or database connection problem, you would not be able to see the front page either.

Ordinarily, Drupal prevents [Clean URLs](http://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls) from being activated if not supported by the server. In this scenario, of course, that test was done in the Windows installation. Ensuring rewriting support in the target server is at the top of the [migration checklist](http://drupal.org/node/333675).

The quickest way to see if Clean URLs is the culprit is to try browsing to `localhost/sitename/index.php?q=user/login` ; if that page does come up, you will need to enable rewriting in your web server.

See http://drupal.org/node/1186762#comment-5424052 for some instructions on checking your Apache configuration to make sure it allows Drupal to rewrite URLs in its .htaccess file.

If you can confirm that the .htaccess file is being read, rewrite directives have been allowed in Drupal's installation directory, and that mod_rewrite is active, and still see problems, I would check next for a corrupted menu table.

Comment: Yes the problem was Apache's rewrite problem.                      sudo a2enmode rewrite
worked for me . Thanks a lot for the help.